# How to set Default document in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, default

How can i set different default document for each folder in my asp.net project.
I have set a default document from IIS, but that doesn't show up for every folder browsed.
I have already added HTMLs to the collection but they are not showing up, instead stander ed Forbidden error page shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can do this by setting all the different pages in the default document collection and then creating those pages in the folder you want to have redirect. the IIS will automatically select the nearest available page for showing.

Good Luck..

Answer (score 1):

You can add default.aspx to each folder and then when Page_Load occurs call Response.Redirect("URL_TO_YOUR_PAGE") to document you want to be default.

Hope it will help you.

Best regards, Dima.

Comment: I already know abt that, but it is not the clean way of doing it, Default Document is a feature ment for that, it would be better if you can suggest somthing with that.  AnyWay Thanx for your answer